# Is there a way to pass data between a service and an activity without start the latter?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, intentservice

I'm making a galley app and I have created a background service with an IntentService that classifies images so I want to send them to an activity that will show them whenever the user wants, for this reason, I don't want to open the activity right after the service finished the task. I have read that you can use SharedPreferences to share data between activities but according to the Android documentation you can only pass a relatively small collection of key-values. In my case, I want to send an ArrayList of files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending list of files, you can just send the absolute path or files. So it would be only a list of strings

Comment: I cannot do that cause I should change many things of the structure of the code, the files that the service processes are pre-process by an activity, and each of  those files are sent to the service inside a holder class that provides extra methods to work with... Sorry if I'm not clear! I don't speak English..